# Cómo podría añadir algún sonido de fondo en una página web usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy trabajando en un miniproyecto de un juego, y me gustaría agregar un sonido de fondo a mi página web utilizando JavaScript. He intentado esto, pero no he logrado que funcione como esperaba.:

```js
const backgroundAudio = document.querySelector(".background_audio")

// Events
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  backgroundAudio.play();
});
```

```html
<audio class="background_audio" loop>
      <source src="./Point Being - Go By Ocean _ Ryan McCaffrey.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
      Tu navegador no soporta el elemento audio
    </audio>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, orientación o ejemplos de código que puedan proporcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar crear la etiqueta audio en memoria y no fisicamente en el documento html, intenta esto:

```
const audio = new Audio("./Point Being - Go By Ocean _ Ryan McCaffrey.mp3");
audio.play();
```

Otra forma es crear ese elemento desde javascript con createElement:

```
const audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.preload = "auto";
audio.src = "./Point Being - Go By Ocean _ Ryan McCaffrey.mp3";
audio.play();
```

puedes incluso usar el metodo loop() para repetirlo; espero te ayude